# c++ thread-safe singleton good for VC++

Tags: visual-c++, singleton

I'm looking for thread-safe c++ singleton which can be used in VC++.
Just declaring instance as local static variable doesn't work because VC++ doesn't support "Magic statics" feature of c++11 yet.

Could someone post full example of singleton which will:

- work in latest version of VC++
- thread-safe
- full (just compile and use, no modification required)
- tested
- fast if possible

Comment: How about _no singleton_? All your singleton problems are solved automagically by not using singletons!